Stretch Singleband Pseudocolor with Cumulative Cut
I'd like to use the QGIS Python Console to stretch a raster layer that's already symbolized as Singleband Pseudocolor. I can push either button, , but I'd rather script it for a layer(s). The only part I don't know how to do is the stretch to cumulative cut based on full extent. Here is an example of how I'm guessing it should be done, but I was hoping there was already this functionality in PqQGIS without having to create the ramp in code?
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal

# Color list (percentile, color)
colors = [
  (2, QColor(48,18,59),
  (4, QColor(50,21,67),
  ...
  (96, QColor(122,4,3),
  (98, QColor(133,7,2)
]
for layer in iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers():
  ds = gdal.Open(layer.source())
  band1 = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
  ramp_list = []
  for color in colors:
    value = np.nanpercentile(band1, color[0])
    ramp_item = QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(value, color[1])
    ramp_list.append(ramp_item)
  fnc = QgsColorRampShader()
  fnc.setColorRampType(QgsCOlorRampShader.Interpolated)
  fnc.setColorRampItemList(ramp_list)
  shader = QgsRasterShader
  shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fnc)
  renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(layer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
  layer.setRenderer(renderer)

The examples I have found seem to require doing the math to find the max, min, and steps and match them to the color wanted. This seems doable with a simple color swatch but I require almost every color. This is an example.


I have a hundred of these per project to stretch which takes a long time when the rasters are large.
